# How to give animation for the texture in open gl iphone?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es-2.0, xcode4.3

I am new to iphone development. Currently I am working on a project where opengl is used and I need to animate a part of the view. For that I have taken the screen shot and then created the texture.

This is my code

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_SRC_COLOR);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.introductionTextLabel.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

GLuint      texture[1];
glGenTextures(1, &texture[0]);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR); 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);

GLuint width = CGImageGetWidth(viewImage.CGImage);
GLuint height = CGImageGetHeight(viewImage.CGImage);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
void *imageData = malloc( height * width * 4 );
CGContextRef contextTexture = CGBitmapContextCreate( imageData, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big );

CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
CGContextClearRect( contextTexture, CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height ) );
CGContextTranslateCTM( contextTexture, 0, height - height );
CGContextDrawImage( contextTexture, CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height ), viewImage.CGImage );

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);


CGContextRelease(contextTexture);

free(imageData);
```

I have searched a lot but could not find a good method for giving an animation for the texture.

Can any one suggest me good method. If I am doing wrong please point out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can recommend you to modify the texture is to use `glTexImage2D()` for full frame update and `glTexSubImage2D()` for partial update. Of course it will be better if you will use preloaded and compressed type of textures...